# jQuery dropdown menu only opens once on iPhone

Tags: jquery, html, css, iphone, mobile

I've created a dropdown menu that works perfect both on desktop as on mobile devices. However when browsing on my iPhone the dropdown menu only works once (that is: Open the menu - Click on a link - *menu closes*). Trying to click the menu-icon a second time won't show the dropdown list.

I beleive i've missed something about how mouseover/mouseout works on mobile devices but have no idea of whats wrong!

Here's my jQuery related to the dropdown menu

```
$('header nav').mouseover(function () {
            $(this).children().show();

            //When clicking on the menu on the iPhone -> Close menu
            $('header nav li a').on('click touchend', function () {
                $(this).parent().parent().hide();
            });
        });

 $('header nav').mouseout(function () {
            $(this).children().hide();
        });
}
```

Scroll functionality

```
$('header li a, .logo, .down, .subheader .btn, footer .container > a').on('click touchend', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - top_ofset
    }, 1500);
});
```

**EDIT:**

Added "toggle()" instead of hide/show and "click()" instead of mouseover, still only works once on iPhone

```
$('header nav').click(function () {
        $(this).children().toggle();
        $('header nav li a').on('click touchend', function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().toggle();
        });
    });
```

Comment: you will have to consider using `click` events for mobile touch devices

Comment: added `click` and `toggle`. Still only works once on iPhone :/

Comment: comment e.preventDefault(); and then try, and let me know if it works or not

Comment: yep you're correct, it has something to do with e.preventDefault. However, I'd like to keep `e.preventDefault()` since scrollTop() makes the page flicker otherwise..